# Issue starting applications with environmental variable

Tags: environment-variables

I want to be able to start application, any application, with this command `HOME=/home/user/data appname`, and application to save its data in `data` folder, basically changing the home location of the application. The issue is, for example, if i start mousepad on Xubuntu with this command `HOME=/home/user/mousedata mousepad` it starts the appilcation, but mousepad doesn't save its settings in `mousedata` folder. The same happens with any other application. Why is that? What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing forces any application to use $HOME. There are [other system interfaces](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) that provide that information and that do not rely on $HOME.

Comment: So, there is no way to change the location where application saves its data?

Comment: Not if the files are directly in $HOME. If they are in a subdirectory, you can create a softlink with that name to another directory. Now if the question is specifically about `mousepad`, this is Linux, you can recompile your own after changing where it save its data. Modern apps don't save in `$HOME` but in `$HOME/.config`, usually, but this is the same problem as $HOME, you can't move it without impacting all other apps.

Comment: Every application handles changing data/config file locations differently. Read its man page. You can probably set an environment variable or alias `application` to `application --data-dir /home/user/mousedata`. If you want to make your applications follow the XDG scheme, see [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory)

Comment: I was looking for a simple solution, like starting firefox with different profile: `firefox -profile /path-to-profile`, but i guess there is not. I will check archwiki and what XDG scheme means.

Comment: I tried to execute this command: `mousepad --data-dir /home/user/mousedata` but i get this error: `(mousepad:1942): Mousepad-ERROR **: 11:03:27.209: Unknown option --data-dir
Trace/breakpoint trap`